# Spring Boot Autowired null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have several classes in a Spring Boot project, some work with @Autowired, some do not. Here my code follows:

Application.java (@Autowired works):

```
package com.example.myproject;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.myproject"})
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.myproject.repository")
@PropertySource({"classpath:db.properties", "classpath:soap.properties"})
public class Application {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}

@Bean
public SOAPConfiguration soapConfiguration() {
    SOAPConfiguration SOAPConfiguration = new SOAPConfiguration();
    SOAPConfiguration.setUsername(environment.getProperty("SOAP.username"));
    SOAPConfiguration.setPassword(environment.getProperty("SOAP.password"));
    SOAPConfiguration.setUrl(environment.getProperty("SOAP.root"));
    return SOAPConfiguration;
}
```

HomeController (@Autowired works):

```
package com.example.myproject.controller;

@Controller
class HomeController {

    @Resource
    MyRepository myRepository;
```

MyService (@Autowired does not work):

```
package com.example.myproject.service;

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    public SOAPConfiguration soapConfiguration; // is null

    private void init() {
    log = LogFactory.getLog(MyServiceImpl.class);
    log.info("starting init, soapConfiguration: " + soapConfiguration);
    url = soapConfiguration.getUrl(); // booom -> NullPointerException
```

I do not get the SOAPConfiguration but my application breaks with a null pointer exception when I try to access it.

I have already read many Threads here and googled around, but did not find a solution yet. I tried to deliver all necessary information, please let me know if anything misses.

Comment: From where are you calling the `init` method? I suspect the constructor.

Comment: log.info prints: starting init, soapConfiguration: null

Comment: HomeController.update creates a new MyServiceImpl and calls myService.update which calls its init method.

Comment: If you are creating new instances yourself spring will not autowire them, spring will only inject into bean instances it knows about. Why do you need a new instance each time?

Comment: HomeController is not a bean instance too, but injection works.

Comment: Yes it is... Due to the `@Controller` and the `@ComponentScan` it is automatically detected and managed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you call `init()` before the autowiring takes place. Annotate `init()` with @PostConstruct to make it call automatically after all the spring autowiring.

EDIT: after seeing your comment, I guess you are creating it using `new MyServiceImpl()`. This takes away the control of the MyServiceImpl from Spring and gives it to you. Autowiring won't work in those case

Comment: I added the @PostContruct annotation, but soapConfiguration is still null.

Answer (score 2):

Did you created a bean for the class SOAPConfiguration in any of your configuration classes? If you want to autowire a class in your project, you need to create a bean for it. For example,

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public SOAPConfiguration createSOAPConfiguration(){

        return new SOAPConfiguration();
    }

}

public class SomeOtherClass{

    @Autowired
    private SOAPConfiguration soapConfiguration;
}
```

Comment: The Application.java should do that? As in my explanation?

Comment: Are you sure the method on your Application.java called for SOAPConfiguration?